# Make tailwind disabled variant work with any element EX: div, li

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a clickable list

```
<li type="button" class="bg-gray-100 disabled:bg-red-700" disabled="disabled">
    Item 1 - disabled
</li>
<li type="button" class="bg-gray-100 disabled:bg-red-700">
    Item 1 - enabled
</li>
```

I planned to apply the disabled attribute to each li in the list was disabled. But it seemed this didn't work. I can see the class is being added in my tailwind output folder but it doesn't seem to be taking effect.

Adding this to the tailwind config seems to be partially the solution

```
  variants: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: ['disabled']
   },
  },
```

However, even this doesn't seem to fix this issue for me. That's when i found out it seems the disabled attribute doesn't seem to get applied to certain elements like div and li elements.

so is there some way around this or alternative to using tailwind disabled: variant?

for example is there a way to make a variant that is applied when some arbitrary data attribute is detected?

for example I'm thinking something like adding a data-disabled attribute instead and then adding the tailwind class via something like [data-disabled]:bg-red-500

but i don't think that syntax is valid. is there something like that which i could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an arbitrary variant to style the item if it has the `data-disabled` attribute.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="bg-gray-100 [&[data-disabled]]:bg-red-700" data-disabled>
    Item 1 - disabled
  </li>
  <li class="bg-gray-100 [&[data-disabled]]:bg-red-700">
    Item 1 - enabled
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or, with data attribute variants:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="bg-gray-100 data-[disabled]:bg-red-700" data-disabled>
    Item 1 - disabled
  </li>
  <li class="bg-gray-100 data-[disabled]:bg-red-700">
    Item 1 - enabled
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for. 

However, I have a small follow up question. 

technically I could also do `[&[disabled]]:bg-red-700` which works the same but allows me to continue to work with the default disabled attribute. Do you think doing that is ok would doing that be risky in terms of how everything interacts?

Comment: @MatteCrystal That would also work, but it's generally better practice to not mess with standard attributes.